# How can I Implement fast-fail strategy in jdbc driver loading?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm practicing java web application, I have a question about DAO Object and JDBC.

When my web application fails to load MySQL driver class, I want to terminate the web app according to 'fast-fail' strategy. for that, The `ClassNotFoundException` of `Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);` should not be caught by `try-catch`.

**(added more explanation)**

However, the code has an logical error without `try-catch`. there is red underline in eclipse IDE with `Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException`. I don't know how to implement 'fast-fail'.

My question is...

1. How do you implement `Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);`, which class, method, ... etc?
   (I don't want to execute that every data requests)
2. Is it appropriate to apply a fail-fast strategy?
3. If so, How can I terminate it when the code throws `ClassNotFoundException`?

I use Apache Tomcat and here is my code.

TodoDao.java

```java
public class TodoDao {    
    private static final String GET_TODOS = "SELECT id, title, name, regDate, sequence, type"
                                         + " FROM   todo"
                                         + " ORDER  BY regdate DESC;";

    public TodoDao() {
        DBConnection.updateDriver();  // fast-fail
    }

    public List<TodoDto> getTodos() {
        // ...skip
    }
}
```

DBConnection.java

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {
    private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/boostcourse"
                                       + "?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=utf8";
    private static final String DB_USER = "testuser";
    private static final String DB_PASSWD = "test1234!";
    
    public static final void updateDriver() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
    }
    
    public static final Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD);
    }
}
```

MainServlet.java(call dao)

```java
// ...skip

@WebServlet(UriInfo.MAIN)
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MainServlet() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        TodoDao dao = new TodoDao();
        List<TodoDto> todos = dao.getTodos();

        request.setAttribute("todos", todos);

        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/main.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"However, the code has an error without try-catch."_ What error? Please provide a [mre] and all relevant information.

Comment: @Mark It is just logical Error about unhandled Exception. I thought the web app wouldn't shut down if I caught and handled the error. so I don't want to handle the exception. I added more description to the question.

Comment: That was my guess, but it is important to be explicit about your problems when asking questions on stack overflow. You'll get an answer quicker, and it improves being able to find questions through a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

```
public TodoDao() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    DBConnection.updateDriver();  // fast-fail
}
```

This approach just puts off the problem.  Now the caller of `TodoDao` has to deal with it.

```
public TodoDao() {
    try {
        DBConnection.updateDriver();  // fast-fail
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot load JDBC driver class", ex);
    }
}
```

This approach rethrows the exception as an unchecked exception so that the caller doesn't have to deal with it.  You could (and probably should) declare and use a custom unchecked exception rather than throwing `RuntimeException`.

However, it looks to me as if the sole purpose of `TodoDao` is to force loading of the database driver.  So why don't you just declare it as per the first solution ... and handle the exception in the caller ... which is *presumably* in a place where you can deal with the configuration error; e.g. by abandoning servlet initialization.

Comment: Could you help me more? I'm trying a second way, declared my custom exception called `DriverNotLoadedException`. but  I get an error - `Unhandled exception type DriverNotLoadedException`, and after running I get and error - `java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Unhandled exception type DriverNotLoadedException`... what should I do to solve it?

Comment: You want it to be an unchecked exception, so it needs to have `RuntimeException` as its superclass (directly or indirectly).  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html